# Show records related to each user only mvc 5

Tags: database, authentication, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I haven't read much about authentication, but every time I try to I don't get to what I need.
Anyway is there a value each user gets while signed in ? 
Something I can use to filter results to send back to the view, basically just show the data that user created.
For example is there a userId property that changes everytime a user is logged in ? And stays constant for each user ? 
I would've created one myself but I'm not sure how I could make that value change depending on which user logs in.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use their name?

```
   this.User.Identity.Name
```

Or am I missing something?